# The latest concerning Valiant-Vazirani

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, lower-bounds

I'm wondering what the best method obtained for [the Valiant-Vazirani theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valiant%E2%80%93Vazirani_theorem) is.  We can state the following criteria:

(1) First and foremost, has anyone been able to derandomize it?

(2) If not, what is the best running time for converting a SAT instances?  And how does this method work?  Can we somehow do better than the technique mentioned [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/ST07/scribe/lect12.pdf)?

(3) Out of curiosity, I'd also like to know the size bounds of the converted SAT formula.

The reason I ask is that I'm studying an algorithm that makes use of this, so I'd like to have the best technique available.

Comment: Possibly related to your first question about derandomizing the isolation lemma: http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2011/151/

Comment: Have you looked at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7552/derandomizing-valiant-vazirani ?  From the way you phrase this question, it appears not.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon: I have seen it, but I haven't had time to explore it.  I'm still interested in the fastest conversion from SAT to UNIQUE-SAT.