# P=BPP and derandomizing Vazirani-Valiant?

Tags: big-picture, derandomization

Vazirani-Valiant reduction is a randomized reduction from $SAT$ to unambiguous $SAT$.

<s>1. Is $P=BPP$ strong enough to derandomize Vazirani-Valiant reduction?</s>

<s>2. If not what other ingredients are necessary to derandomize Vazirani-Valiant reduction?</s>

The above two are addressed in [Derandomizing Valiant-Vazirani?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7552/derandomizing-valiant-vazirani). However we can still ask whether there is a possibility of $P$ is not $BPP$ and still if it would be possible to derandomize Vazirani-Valiant.

3. Is $P=BPP$ necessary to derandomize Vazirani-Valiant reduction?
4. If not what would derandomizing Vazirani-Valiant reduction tell about $P=BPP$?

Comment: The following question might be helpful: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7552/derandomizing-valiant-vazirani?rq=1

Comment: I believe 1 and 2 are basically a duplicate of the question Or pointed to, and are essentially answered there. I suggest to focus the question down to 3 and 4, and just point out as background that the other question essentially answers the opposite direction.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow ok I will update.